# Passing parameters to JasperReports SQLl statement from Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports engine, and one of the reports gets data from database executing SQL statement. Is there a way to pass parameters to that query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is it if more than 1 parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create a new parameter in your report. Then insert the parameter in your query, for example:

```sql
SELECT name, department FROM employees WHERE employee_id = $P{employeeId}
```

Make sure your parameter types matches the data type of the columns in your database. Finally, simply pass your parameters to the `JasperReports` engine. An example would be:

```java
parameters.put("employeeId", Long.valueOf(14309));
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile, parameters, connection);
```