# Passing parameter to iReport 5.1.0 through jsp

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to pass parameters from jsp to a query which is on the jdbc database connection on *iReport*. And finally run the report on the *iReport*. Is it possible or not?

OR

Can we pass a link of *iReport* from jsp so that we can use *iReport* to run reports. Is it possible or not?

Comment: The *iReport* is a GUI designer for constructing templates (jrxml). What is a reason to call a standalone application, IDE from *jsp*?

Comment: Sir, reason is that we want to create report only using ireport and jasperreport server, and created report using ireport is send to jasper server repository . then finally there is link of jasper server on jsp page so that on clicking this link user can view the jasper server page in which created report is visible to user and he can export it as pdf,excel etc...  sir givwe me idea how it is possible and how it is implemented

Comment: I think it is a very bad idea to use *iReport* to show report for end-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to JasperReports SQLl statement from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733806/passing-parameters-to-jasperreports-sqll-statement-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [**REFER**](http://java4practices.blogspot.in/2012/08/create-jasper-report-in-netbeans.html#more)

//Specify Your Report Path

```
JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport("Report\\report3.jrxml");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conn =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tally" , "root", "root");
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        String queryString = "SELECT category.`accountno` AS 
        category_accountno,  category.`name` AS category_name,category.`type` 
        AS category_type FROM `category` category WHERE accountno
        BETWEEN 100 and 111";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        JRResultSetDataSource jasperReports = new JRResultSetDataSource(rset);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null, jasperReports);

  //By using this VIEWREPORT
         JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint); 

//Report saved in specified path
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"D:\\b1.pdf");
//Report open in Runtime
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " +"D:\\b1.pdf");
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I get solution to this problem, I send my report to jasper server using jasper repository on ireport , And then run the report on the jasper server and passing parameter to url on server.